# Can Wizards wear cloaks and capes instead of robes?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, armor

Can wizards wear cloaks or capes instead of robes? I know armor is not allowed because it prevents the movement needed to perform spells but a cloak or a cape is not specified in the PHB, at least not that I've noticed.

Comment: I would hope that you're not wearing the cloak/cape *instead* of robes, as that would be awfully drafty and there are probably indecent-exposure laws you'd run afoul of.

Comment: Armour is allowed, you just need proficiency.

Comment: @GMJoe: Suddenly I want to play a wizard who wears a kilt and keeps his material components in his sporran.

Comment: Just for future reference, the faulty premise that this question is based on ("wizards can't wear armor because it interferes with spellcasting in 5E") is properly addressed by this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46516/casting-spells-in-armor

Answer (score 13):

First, let's correct the misconception in your post:

Casters are allowed any armor they want so long as they are proficient in it. Armor does not restrict casting. If your wizard wants to MC into something for armor proficiency or take feats to gain it, that is just fine, allowed and has no affect on his casting of spells.

As to whether he can wear other clothing items beyond robes, I believe the above paragraph answers that. There is absolutely no restriction on what a wizard can cast in.

Comment: Huh. Could've swore it was tagged 3.5e. I guess I have a vision problem. Does anyone have a pair of lenses of true seeing, or did 5e get rid of those as well? :P

Comment: While I up-voted this answer, I think the asker is really trying to get at suggestions for implementing cloaks/capes either as stand-alone magic items as in previous editions or possibly even to function as armor and take the place of traditional torso-worn armor pieces.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, wizards can wear cloaks & capes.

They are considered clothing items. A wizard (or anyone else) can wear whatever clothing they like.

Comment: They can even wear pants, if pressed.

Comment: @mxyzplk, IMC I permit wrinkled pants.