# Is there an official Pathfinder "Mana" system for wizards?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, wizard

I thought about the idea of a mana system, and I know at that people have homebrewed it for 3.5 before, but i wanted to know if there was a mana or rechargable spell point system for wizards and magi (magus) in pathfinder.

I'm looking for a spell system to allow a magus to use these points for spells costing a specific amount per level, and may or may not be able to be regained through an alchemical item (basically an ether) [the alchemical item can be ignored if that is too powerful]

Comment: What do you mean by "mana"?  There are several different definitions to that word when talking about systems of magic, and it would help if you described more specifically what you were looking for.

Comment: Well. I was hoping for a system where you an otherwise prepared caster (Like a magus) could use a pool of arcane energy (I don't mean his arcane pool class feature though) To Use for spells, but not necessarily something wizards can do

Comment: Also, I say "rechargeable" in the idea like a video game where you get a certain about of Mana or MP to cast with, but then need to regain that mana to cast more spells

Comment: Are you sure that D&D/PF is the game for you? You've been asking a lot of questions about doing things that it doesn't normally do. Maybe you'd be happier with a game that already does what you're looking for?

Comment: Well, I'm paranoid about magus spell preperation.

Comment: You can't really mess up a Magus's prep.  Snag as many copies of your highest damage touch spell at each level as you have slots, spellstrike until you're empty, rest and repeat.  I mean, sure, you *could* try using their spells for something besides reducing hp, but if you were ever going to do that, you'd have picked arcanist in the first place, which is basically a full-caster variant of the magus with more interesting things to do with their arcane pool.

Comment: Please edit your clarifications into your question. Also consider asking about the actual problem you have in your question instead of your intended solution, if you think other suggestions besides "spell points" would be useful to you.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate of the underlying problem: [Should I worry about "picking the wrong spell" for a prepared caster?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59041/should-i-worry-about-picking-the-wrong-spell-for-a-prepared-caster)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's a question I wrote

Comment: Yes it is. If this question here exists because you're still paranoid about picking the wrong spells, it is worth going back and re-reading that other question's answers, especially the one you accepted as solving the problem of being paranoid about it.

Answer (score 10):

There is a supplement, [Houserule Handbooks: Spell Points](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8u7g?Houserule-Handbooks-Spell-Points), that introduces a point-based system for spellcasters. It's received favorable reviews and the PDF is only $5 on Paizo's site.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want to do is require wizards to use some alchemical fluff to prepare spells, then you don't have to do anything.  Adding fluff like "training time" or "spell component costs" has a long history in Pathfinder's lineage, and so long as you don't make it exceptionally hard to obtain the alchemy, or otherwise make working magic unreasonably expensive, you don't need to do much of anything.

For a real mechanical switch from spell slots to "mana", the closest you'll likely come to an "official Pathfinder mana system for wizards" is the the [OGL Spell Point System from 3.5's Unearthed Arcana](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/magic/spellPoints.htm).  It covers the basic of switching from "spell slots" to "spell points", and leaves the rest of the magic system untouched.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [psionics](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion) rules, as they pretty much work that way (although i'm not sure an "ether" analog exists).
As for actually changing the rest of the spellcasting classes it could get weird if it lets the wizard cast spells without preparation as it would break the sorcerer's main advantage. For that, the answer provided by [Christopher Mathieu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/59484/16138) might be better.

Answer (score -1):

I homebrewed a simple mana system that my DM agreed with and a fellow player loved (he didn't like the default system).

Basically, you convert the levels of your spells per day into mana points. So a level 3 Wizard can cast: 2 1st level spells, and 1 2nd level spell. This converts to: Number of Spells X Spell Level e.g. 2 1st level spells = 2x1=2, 1 2nd level spell = 1x2=2, 2+2=4. So the Wizard has 4 mana/magic points or whatever you want to call it.

Spells cost their spell level in Mana Points, so this system lets you cast the same number of spells, but it grants the freedom of what spells you can cast, you can blow all your Mana on a few high level spells, or make it last by using only low level spells.

Clerics using this system would have a separate Mana pool of Divine Mana for their domain spell list, rather than one big mana pool for spells from both lists.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a look at the [tour] and [help]. While this answer is potentially useful to implement a mana/spell point system, note that the question *specifically* asks for *official systems* rather than homebrew solutions.