# Prestige class progression with multiple base classes: mix and match?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

When you take a prestige class that advances your spellcasting, and you have more than one spellcasting class, can you have some of the prestige class levels progress one base class, and some the other, or must all levels advance the same class?

For example, if an abjurant champion has levels in both duskblade and wizard, can the five levels of abjurant champion count as two levels of wizard and three levels of duskblade?

Answer (score 4):

## Abjurant champion: yes

> If you had more than one arcane
> spellcasting class before becoming an abjurant champion, you
> must decide to which class to add **each level** for the purpose of
> determining spells per day, caster level, and spells known.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

Abjurant champion’s Spellcasting class feature, quoted in part here, specifically addresses this question: you decide which class to add *each level* to. Thus, you can make a different choice each time.

## In general: *usually*

Most spellcasting prestige classes use wording similar to abjurant champion, but it’s not a default or assumed rule: each prestige class must specify itself how *it* works. In fact, there *is no* default or assumed rule: a prestige class that didn’t say one way or the other would be incomplete, and the DM would have to make a houserule to define it.

<sup>*Example removed for not actually being a proper example; will try to find another.*</sup>

---

For the sake of mentioning it, there is really no reason for a duskblade/wizard to want to advance duskblade spellcasting. Duskblade spellcasting is very weak, and the duskblade’s Arcane Channeling feature applies to **all spells**, not just duskblade spells. Advancing duskblade spellcasting also does not help you to get Arcane Channeling, since that is a class feature separate from spellcasting. Therefore, a fairly typical path here would be Duskblade 3/Wizard 4/Abjurant Champion 5, progressing wizard with all five wizard levels, so that you can use your 9th-level wizard spellcasting in conjunction with Arcane Channeling.

Comment: *When a new loremaster level is gained* and *adds the level of loremaster* still implies the decision is made upon gaining the new level rather than once *ever*, or is your reading different?

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, my reading was just *quick*, and I missed that. Darn, now I’m going to have to search for an example. I don’t want to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I believe it would have to be dusk blade 4 wizard 2 or dusk blade 5 wizard 1(which would give you quick cast 1 ability) for the +5 base attack needed for Abjurant Champion. Also wizard spells still have spell failure chance if you are still in armor.

Comment: In this build would you be able to use quick cast on wizard spells?

Comment: @Nathtfm As an abjurant champion, you don't need armor, but if you really want it, [arcane spell failure is easily handled](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/18469/4563). You want to maximize wizard spellcasting. And yes, Quick Cast works with all spells, but it's not worth two more lost wizard levels.